# Unable to get the vlookup property

Tags: vlookup

Attached image is my my table from which I am trying to fetch the value of the input.

[image]

I have written a lookup statement for that. However I get error "unable to get the vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class"

I have stored the input in "Postcode".if the postcode is AB1 0, it has to return value 0.

```
PC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Postcode, _
    Worksheets("G010").Range("A2:A12610"), 2, True)
```

Comment: Please include the relevant data directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have is that you will never find something in the second column of an array that has only one column.